# Tridion 2009 Events System to 2011 SP1

Tags: tridion, tridion2009

Upgrading .Net Events system from Tridion 2009 to Tridion 2011 SP1.

Does anyone have a brief overview of the steps involved?

What is the replacement for Events Config XML file to limit events to particular publications?

I have reviewed the subscribe approach implemented by the new Events system but can events be applied per publication. So far the only approach seems to be implementing publication filter logic in code rather than configuration?

Any input greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a really good place to get started. Written by [Bart Koopman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1220542/bart-koopman)

http://www.sdltridionworld.com/articles/sdltridion2011/sdltridion2011eventsystem.aspx

It includes a [matrix](http://www.sdltridionworld.com/images/event_matrix_tcm89-18738.pdf) for mapping old events to the new event phases.

To the best of my knowledge, you still need to choose whether or not to execute your code from within your code depending on the publication. You can not subscribe to a particular event for a specific publication.